# openpyxl: Gives error on load_workbook()

Tags: python, openpyxl

The following code was executing fine, until I setup the development environment on a different computer.

```
workbook_obj = load_workbook(filename=xl_file, data_only=True, use_iterators=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_iterators'
```

A `pip freeze` command shows that I was using `openpyxl 2.3.5` previously when the code worked fine. My current version is `2.4.0`.

Is this a bug in `openpyxl`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `use_iterators` keyword [was removed](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html?highlight=use_iterators#a1-2016-04-11) since 2.4.0. Use `read_only=True` instead.